# What are good resources for learning to test using Selenium for a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium

I am looking for resources to learn how to use Selenium to test my rails app?

How are people using it etc.

I know the people at pivotal use Selenium, I'm looking for an insiders view on how to use it effectively and efficiently etc.

Answer (score 0):

My goto place to look for rails info has always been Railscasts: http://railscasts.com/episodes/116-selenium

After that `Google++`